# Can VCC be supplied by external power supply?

Tags: microcontroller, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction, vcc

I've implemented the following 80W PFC boost pre-regulator presented in the following application note. I built the inductor and its auxiliary winding myself with another magnetic core and its specifications such as the number of primary and auxiliary turns are not the exact ones mentioned in the application note. so I'm worried that maybe the self-supply network requires modification due to these changes. is there any problem if I delete the self-supply circuit for early tests and supply the VCC with a 15V DC Power supply? my attitude is to observe the correct operation of the circuit and then attempt to redesign the self-supply components' values.
https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00195944-solution-for-designing-a-transition-mode-pfc-preregulator-with-the-l6562a-stmicroelectronics.pdf
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the standby regulator is needed. And a good example is ATX PSUs: In ATX PSUs there's a separate standby regulator *(mostly a flyback)* which gets its input from the output of the PFC pre-regulator. Since the PFC pre-regulator will be off (due to the inexistence of Vcc) and therefore no switching at start up, what you'll get from the PFC output will be the rectified AC input. So there's no problem for the stby regulator to power up. Once the stby regulator generates stable voltage(s) the Vcc of the PFC controller can be supplied from one of the outputs.

So yes, you can use a separate supply. And if you are planning to generate this stby supply onboard then you can follow the same approach above.

---

*I remember that I used a Fairchild/ONSemi equivalent to the L6562. The chip has an open-drain PG (power good) output so I could use it to run the post regulator once the PFC gets stabilised.*

---

The main disadvantage of supplying through the ZCD winding is that the PFC output needs a minimum load because the ZCD winding "will steal" energy from the main winding which is a boost choke. So at real no-load state, due to the insufficient energy stored in the main winding's magnetic field, the chip may not be supplied properly from the aux winding. This pushes the chip to get its supply through start up resistors and therefore the losses will increase.